# PAM won't authenticate with mysql (make_scrambled_password deprecated)

Tags: mysql, postfix, pam, arch-linux, saslauthd

I have spent some time searching for this and it seems I'm the only one having problem with PAM not authenticating through mysql due to current updates so I thought I will post my problem here and if I find solution I will post here as well for others to follow.

In short - I'm running postfix with saslauthd and dovecot. Both are authenticating through pam employing mysql as credentials source.

Everything was working fine until today update - I can't connect to mail server any more and here is what I see in logs:

```
PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib/security/pam_mysql.so): /usr/lib/security/pam_mysql.so:     undefined symbol: make_scrambled_password
PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib/security/pam_mysql.so
DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Module is unknown
do_auth         : auth failure: [user=xxxx] [service=smtp] [realm=xxxx] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

So I may be wrong but to my understanding pam_mysql.so is using deprecated make_scrambled_password that is not supported by mysql any more.

I don't know what the solution would be and will appreciate if anybody can advice.

---

I checked source code on project page and can see deprecated function is being used. So this seems to be a bug in pam_mysql and update will be needed ([bug reported on pam_mysql sourceforge page][1] as well as on arch community bug tracker (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39083?project=5&pagenum=1))

---

I have seen some workaround patches around internet (https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/scm-commits/2011-June/613231.html) however I'm not sure if that's suitable for production environment.
It seems I will have to patch it myself. I will post patch here for others to use.

Many thanks,
Greg

Comment: Did you update your system? It seems one of the shared libraries that pam_mysql.so uses no longer has the symbol (aka function) "make_scrambled_password". Perhaps reverting to a previous version of that library will fix the problem. Or updating your pam_mysql.so to a newer version (preferable). If this is part of distro packages (and not hand-compiled) then all dependencies should match.

Comment: Thanks Fred. It seems this is other way around - pam_mysql is using make_scrambled_password which was deprecated a while ago and was now ruled out from mysql. I raised bug report with pam_mysql developers (hopefully they are still around) so this can be patched at source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for pam_mysql is now dropped due to project being dead for almost 6 years. Solution will be to migrate and use another pam backend.

I was using cyrus sasl - that was now uninstalled and replaced by dovecot that provides smtpd authentication backend recognized by postfix. I configured dovecot to use sql natively (without pam in the middle).